# Using RenderContext in render_to_string in Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-1.10

I'm upgrading a project to Django 1.10 and trying to change the following template tag (simplified)

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_svg(context, svg_template_file_name, *args, **kwargs):
    svg_string = render_to_string(svg_template_file_name, context, request=context.request)
```

This no longer works since the `context` passed in is a [`RenderContext`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context.py#L187), where  the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#dictionary-and-context-instance-arguments-of-rendering-functions) state:

> If you’re passing a Context in context_instance, pass a dict in the context parameter instead. If you’re passing a RequestContext, pass the request separately in the request parameter.

Which I'm already doing and still would like to make use of the `context` parameter to `render_to_string`...

So how can I get a usable dictionary from a `RenderContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RenderContext`'s base class, `BaseContext`, has a function called [`flatten`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context.py#L128) which will take the array of dictionaries inside a Context object and return a single dictionary

```
render_to_string(svg_template_file_name, context, request=context.request)
```

would need changing to

```
render_to_string(svg_template_file_name, context.flatten(), request=context.request)
```